MobaXterm ssh password paste not working
I need some help with MobaXterm.
I would like to unlock my LUKS crypted disks on my server with dropbear-initramfs.
With the normal PuTTy Client I can connect to the server paste my password by a click on my right mouse button, press enter and the disk is unlocked.
On MobaXterm terminal I can connect to server, type in the password manually and it works. But I am not able to paste the password. I tried all key combination and the the context menu with the paste function. But the paste is not working.
Do somebody has an idea how to solve this?

You tried Shift+Insert which is the default shortcut for MobaXterm

Please list the specific key combinations you have tried and their outcome.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes I tried Shift+Insert, ctrl+v, Shift+right mouse button and paste in context menu, only right mouse button, changed the combination for paste in settings. Nothing happens on terminal. When I press enter, the terminal comment this with blank password. The password is still in the clipboard and it works with the original PuTTy Client.
